# How to get the client IP?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

While this sounds silly, I haven't been able to find a way to get the IP of the client in Play 2.0. It was available in 1.2.x as `Http.Request.remoteAddress`, but 2.0 (I primarily checked the Scala API, but I did a quick check of the Java one too) only seems to provide information about the server side of the request in `play(.api).mvc.Request`. Is there something I'm missing? The closest hack I can think of right now is setting it up behind a reverse proxy and then checking `X-Forwarded-For`, but this doesn't work too well in dev.

Comment: Hi, if you have an Http request, have you tried using a trick with `play.api.http.HeaderNames.FROM`and the request header you can probably get somehow?

Comment: From -The email address of the user making the request. Not sure if this will work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

EDIT:Coming back to this answer, this was added in playframework 2.0.2: see release announcement on  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/Z97GQ2VnR5M/T-STGaeuN68J%5B1-25%5D and more importantly the API documentation at http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Request

As you can see there is now support for `Request.remoteAddress`

Original:

There is currently a bug open for this in the tracker: https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401/tickets/256-add-back-requestheaderremoteaddress

I think that hacking the play2.0 libraries to include the linked patch is currently the best bet. It is probably still cleaner than to use a proxy with the sole purpose of adding XFF headers, and using those to determine the IP.

Comment: Actually, I posted that, and I'm the one who made that patch.

Comment: I think by now we can safely assume this was an `Oops` by the Play team. Shame nobody noticed it before 2.0 final. Maybe the bugreport will still go 'no you can do it easily some other way'. But I doubt it.

Comment: yeah, that was my thought too, after being unable to find it. That feeling was then reinforced by Olivier's answer which references http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/HTTPServer which actually references request.remoteAddress (although that doesn't actually exist).

Comment: The patch has been merged, so now we wait

Answer (score 8):

Please check this Github project at https://github.com/orefalo/play2-xforward

I took the code from Play1 and ported it to Play2, it should work the same.

Still a work in progress...

Comment: are you sure? it is read as such `lazy val host: String = headers.get(play.api.http.HeaderNames.HOST).getOrElse("")` seems to me as it is read from the request. It can't be the local IP/domain. Now if you read the post, it explains how to preserve the original host with a `ProxyPreserveHost On`

Comment: The host header is the domain/IP (possibly with port) that you type in the address field it's there to avoid needing a new IP for every domain.

Comment: I need this info to.. found the code from Play1. might help, let me update my answer

Comment: Http.Request.remoteAddress was removed between 1.2.x and 2.0. Compare http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.2.4/play/mvc/Http.Request.html#remoteAddress to http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/java/play/mvc/Http.Request.html .

Comment: I know it has, but the code above gives you all the details to re-implement it. Your/mine concern it the get the remote IP, I personally don't care if the method is attached to a Request. Think I need to write a module for this guy..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9146/discussion-between-olivier-refalo-and-nullable)