# How to get IP address of the client in Play! framework 2.0?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the client IP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711793/how-to-get-the-client-ip)

How to get ip of the client in Play! framework 2.0? Is something implemented in Play? Any help, advices? I'm writing apps in Java.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In Play 2.0's  action you can get lot of data from [Http.RequestHeader](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/java/play/mvc/Http.RequestHeader.html) it can be fetched like this:

```
public static Result index() {
    String remote = request().remoteAddress();
    return ok(remote);
}
```

Comment: But unfortunately it gives 127.0.0.1 all the time...

Comment: Of course, because your local address is such, use other device in the same net, ie. other computer or mobile phone to access the application - it will show you 192.168.1.123 (for an example)

Comment: Is this approach always valid? and get correct client ip?

Comment: If you're hosting your app on a cloud, you could get the internal IP address of the routing nodes. See [the doc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/HTTPServer#advanced-proxy-settings) for more information.

Comment: if you use localhost:9000 then it will always give the 127.0.0.1 but using http://127.0.0.1:9000/Yourapp might do the trick