# How to capture requestor IP address in play java framework?

Tags: java, rest, playframework-2.0, ip-address

I am hosting my play REST API in a remote unix machine with a.b.c.d ip address and trying to trigger the routes from my browser in windows machine with different IP address. In the code I am trying to capture IP address and hostname of requestor using request().remoteAddress() and request().host() methods but every time I get IP address of the unix machine not the requestor address. How do I capture requestor IP?

Comment: may work ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678797/how-do-i-get-the-remote-address-of-a-client-in-servlet

Comment: This has Play! specific info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721215/how-to-get-ip-address-of-the-client-in-play-framework-2-0